# How do I set the title tag for the maintenance page?

Tags: theming, 8, maintenance-mode

I need to change the default title tag for the maintenance page, which currently is "Site under maintenance | [sitename]".

I tried to set `$variables['head_title']` in `hook_preprocess_maintenance_page()` but it doesn't work.

Also I think it can be set in `hook_preprocess_html()`, but I don't know how to check the served page is the maintenance page.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TEMPLATE_preprocess_maintenance_page` changes only variables for maintenance-page.html.twig. But `<title>` is outputted in html.html.twig, so you have to choose another preprocessor `template_preprocess_html`. So you can use this code(don't forget to clean cache after it):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $maintenance_mode = \Drupal::state()->get('system.maintenance_mode');
  if (!empty($maintenance_mode)) {
    $variables['head_title'] = (string)t('My Custom Maintenance Title');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change this message, you can go Adm -> Config -> Maintenance page and write you own message.

If you really want do this in a preprocess function:

```
function TEMPLATE_preprocess_maintenance_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['head_title'] = "A custom var that YOU going to use in maintenance-page.html.twig";
  $variables['title'] = "Default var used to display title message 'Site under maintenance' ";
}
```

Or you can even override `maintenance-page.html.twig` file to put your own message, but its not the best option.

Comment: In Config -> Maintenance page I can change message only. But I need to change title tag.  
And I already tried using preprocess function for it, but it doesn't affect anything. And it's the problem.

Comment: @paulanders Edit your question to provide more information about your context because there is no title tag or 'head_title' by default in `maintenance-page.html.twig`. Are you using a custom theme, module or whatever? Are you using preprocess functions in a module or a theme? My answer works ok in a clean install of Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

On Drupal 9 with a subtheme from Bootstrap 5, I used this function to change the head title and the page title.

```
/**
 * Implements theme_preprocess_html().
 */
function TEMPLATE_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $maintenance_mode = \Drupal::state()->get('system.maintenance_mode');
  if (!empty($maintenance_mode)) {
    $title = t('My Custom Maintenance Title');
    $variables['head_title']['title'] = $variables['page']['#title'] = $title;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write php code,you can try this↓

Since the maintenance setting page(/admin/config/development/maintenance) supports JS,
it may be possible to solve this indirectly by adding the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.title="your custom title"
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

If you have access to the backend, you can modify the string directly for a temporary change. Change `/var/www/html/` to the location of your install and other strings to fit your needs.

1. Login with SSH. `ssh root@yourdrupalsite.com`
2. Edit the file `/var/www/html/includes/common.inc` with your favorite text editor and replace `Site under maintenance` with your new message. You could also use sed. `sed -i 's/Site under maintenance/Your new title here/' /var/www/html/includes/common.inc`
3. Clear the cache. `cd /var/www/html/ && drush cc all`

This will be overwritten after an update to Drupal Core.

Comment: That's a very bad idea which is why you're getting downvoted. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/site-building-best-practices/never-hack-core for details.

Comment: It works as a quick temporary fix. It will get overwritten with an update to core.